# AFNetworking POST Error 3840

Tags: ios, objective-c, wcf, swift, afnetworking

I'm running into a service error as I try to POST some data to a server. I'm confident the error has something to do with my request structure. I'm using AFNetworking and my request looks as follows:

```
      lazy var networkManager: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = {

            var networkManager : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
            networkManager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/json",
                forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


            networkManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =
                NSSet(array: ["text/plain", "text/html", "application/json"]) as Set<NSObject>



            return networkManager
            }()

func createNewAccount(username:String, password:String, onCompletion:Closures.ServiceResponse) -> Void{

        let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "newUser": [
                "name": username,
                "password": password
            ]
        ]



        var err : NSError?
        var jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: &err)
        var jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)


        networkManager.POST(Constants.STAGING_URL + "/Services/UserService/UserService.svc/NewUserSignup",
        parameters: jsonString,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            println(responseObject)
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
            println(error.localizedDescription)
            println(operation.responseString)
        })
    }
```

I've tried variations on the parameters option and I still run into the same problem.

Now here is the method I have written by hand that works just fine and sends data to the server as expected:

```
 func signupNewUser(userName : String, password : String){

        let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "newUser": [
                "name": userName,
                "password": password
            ]
        ]

        var urlString = Constants.STAGING_URL + "/Services/UserService/UserService.svc/NewUserSignup"

        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        var err: NSError?
        request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonObject, options: nil, error: &err)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        var jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonObject, options: nil, error: &err)

        var jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        request.setValue(jsonString! as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "json")

         var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            println(response)
        })

        task.resume()

    }
```

The above request works just fine and the server can process the incoming JSON and save it in the database successfully.

My server is a WCF service. The interface for the method I'm calling looks like this:

```
  [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/NewUserSignup")]
        Response  AddNewUser(User newUser);
```

The actual NSError is:

```
Printing description of error:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7f98a0c58910 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f98a0c582f0 "Request failed: bad request (400)"}
```

I assume the server is fine and it just has to do with configuring the request properly with AFNetworking. Any help configuring the request properly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in my case was simple and had to do with the configuration of the NetworkManager.

This worked for me as the NetWorkManager will be receiving JSON from the server:

```
 lazy var networkManager: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = {

        var networkManager : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

        var jsonRequestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()

        networkManager.requestSerializer = jsonRequestSerializer

        return networkManager
        }()
```